# angular.js directive: howto call jquery library for ng-repeat item (with item specific attribute)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Howto render jquery lib (particulary coconut countdown timer) for every ng-repeat item? 
I wrap jquery lib to this directive:

```
.directive('countDownTimer',['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',    
    templateUrl: 'partials/count-down-timer.html',   
    scope: { item_id: '=' }, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $("#countdown" + scope.item_id).coconut({
       startDate: "15/07/2012",
           nowDate: "15/07/2014",
       endDate: "31/05/2015",
    });
    }
  };
}]);

<count-down-timer item_id="model.itemID"></count-down-timer>

partials/count-down-timer.html :
<div id={{'countdown' + item_id}} class="float-left googlefont font-32"></div>

//This doesn't work, but if I change angular expression statically into string eg.
<div id="countdown1" class="float-left googlefont font-32"></div>  it works.
```

Do you know howto fix that problem, or maybe Do you know some another better solution?
Maybe better could be solution which directly bind coconut function on element and avoid referencing thorough itemID so I tried:

```
..
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.coconut({
       startDate: "15/07/2012",
           nowDate: "15/07/2014",
       endDate: "31/05/2015",
    });
..
```

but In this solution render timer for elements but it loks that timers share one together space and badly render time.

btw here is countdown plugin which I use: http://codecanyon.net/item/coconut-jquery-countdown-plugin/full_screen_preview/2919162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution through IDs work if I put ID into link function:

element.attr("id", scope.item_id);

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see 2 mistakes here

**1.** `$("#countdown" + scope.item_id).coconut();`

you never user jquery inside of a directive. you have to do it the angular way `$()` in angular you writte it `angular.element()`

**2.**

in your link function you dont need to go for an id, since the element parameter is acctually your `$("#countdown" + scope.item_id)`

so try with `angular.element(element)`

since you are using isolated scope this should work

Comment: When Do you think this: angular.element(element.coconut({
   startDate: "15/07/2012",
   nowDate: "15/07/2014",
   endDate: "31/05/2015",
}));  it doesn't work. It render timers for elements, but it looks that share same variables, and render bad countdown numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class instead of an id for the inner div like:

```
<div class="countdown float-left googlefont font-32"></div>
```

And then use:

```
element.find('.countdown').coconut({
   startDate: "15/07/2012",
   nowDate: "15/07/2014",
   endDate: "31/05/2015",
}
```

Actually this is quite close to your own solution. The only difference is if you run `coconut()` on the directive element itself, it may overwrite the inner div, so you would lost the `float-left` classes. This may cause them to look strange.

**Update:**
If you want to get your item data from outside the directives, assume that you have `items` like:

```
[
    {
        id: ...
        start_date: ...
        now_date: ...
        end_date: ...
    },
    {
        id: ...
        start_date: ...
        now_date: ...
        end_date: ...
    },
    ...
]
```

I would suggest you do:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <count-down-timer item="item">
</div>
```

And:

```
.directive('countDownTimer',['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',    
        templateUrl: 'partials/count-down-timer.html',   
        scope: { 
            item: '=' 
        }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('.countdown').coconut({
                startDate: scope.item.start_date,
                nowDate: scope.item.now_date,
                endDate: scope.item.end_date
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And for the template at "partials/count-down-timer.html", do sth like:

```
<div class="countdown float-left googlefont font-32"></div>
```

**OR:**

Do:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <count-down-timer item-id="item.id" start-date="item.start_date" now-date="item.now_date" end-date="item.end_date">
</div>
```

And:

```
.directive('countDownTimer',['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',    
        templateUrl: 'partials/count-down-timer.html',   
        scope: { 
            item: '=',
            startDate: '=',
            nowDate: '=',
            endDate: '='
        }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('.countdown').coconut({
                startDate: scope.startDate,
                nowDate: scope.nowDate,
                endDate: scope.endDate
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And for the template at "partials/count-down-timer.html", do the same thing.

Comment: I can't do that because every item have your different dates from this reason I use id. I don't put here this date attributes in directive.

Comment: @markvelkovsky Sorry but I really can not understand your comment... Can you explain more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure, every item in ng-repeat have your specific start-date,end-date. I want to execute timer for every item.

Comment: So your usage of the countDownTimer would be like: <div ng-repeat="item in item"><count-down-timer item_id="item.id"></div>  Right?

Comment: my full usage could be:  <div ng-repeat="item in item"><count-down-timer item_id="item.id" start_date="item.start-date" end_date="item.end-date"></div>

Comment: @markvelkovsky I would suggest you to just use `<div ng-repeat="item in item"><count-down-timer item="item"></div>` , and them you can access them like: `element.find('.countdown').coconut({
   startDate: scope.item.startDate,
   nowDate: scope.item.nowDate,
   endDate: scope.item.endDate
}`

Comment: If you really want to use separate attributes, you will need to add them to your `scope` declaration. You will need `scope: { item_id: '=' , start_date: '=', now_date: '=', end_date: '='},` instead of `scope: { item_id: '=' },`

Comment: Also, it's not a common practice to use _(underscores) in the attribute names of a directive. It's better if you use -(dashes) in html tags and then use camel cased names to retrieve them in your directive code.

Comment: it's not work with element.find it doesn't insert template into directive, but when I try angular.element(element.coconut({ startDate: "15/07/2012", nowDate: "15/07/2014", endDate: "31/05/2015", })); it works but badly render timer time